# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in python using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

code :

```
product_data = []
with open("search_results_urls.txt",'r') as urllist, open('search_results_output.jsonl','w') as outfile:
    for url in urllist.read().splitlines():
        data = scrape(url) 
        if data:
            for product in data['products']:
              if data['products'] is None:
                 continue
              else:
                  product['search_url'] = url
                  print("Saving Product: %s"%product['title'])
                  json.dump(product,outfile)
                  outfile.write("\n")
                  # sleep(5)
        

Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "searchresults.py", line 43, in <module>
    for product in data['products']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How do i resolve this

Comment: As error indicates, your `data['product']` is `None`

Comment: try to print the value of data after `data = scrape(url)`, it looks like `data['products']` is None so you get the error. Or you could add additional check for that as `if data and data['products']`:

Answer (score 1):

```py
for product in data.get('products', []):
  ...
```

When products is None, then an empty list gets passed. An empty list is iterable, so no error will be thrown, but yet nothing will happen.